# jQuery or Javascript Solution Remove Specific Tag but leave the rest

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a div structure that looks like this...

```
<div class="gallery_lightview">
<div id="lg_image">
<a href="http://www.website.com/?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" class="lightview_main" title="TITLE HERE">
<img class="alignnone" src="HEADER.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is remove the `<a>` tags that show up ONLY between div class "gallery_lightview" and leave the `<img>` tag. So once its all stripped out it would look like...

```
<div class="gallery_lightview">
<div id="lg_image">
<img class="alignnone" src="HEADER.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
```

Basically making this a non clickable image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.gallery_lightview').find('img').unwrap();
```

Find the element with class gallery_lightview, find all of its children elements (no matter how deeply nested) that are 'img' elements, then remove each of their immediate parent elements (in this case 'a' tags).

Comment: $('.gallery_lightview a>img').unwrap(); will also work and will make sure that <img> tag is really inside <a>

Answer (score 0):

$('img').insertAfter('a');
Get and insert the element 'a' after 'img'

$('a').remove(); 
Remove the element 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just thought about it a little more. It's actually going on a mobile site. So...I choose not to use jQuery (cut down on the load and because I won't need most of the jQuery functionality).

Anyway this can be done in a self contained Javascript, no in the `<head>`?

I was thinking it would sit right before the Wordpress "`the_content`" call, since this is where the div is in. Any help?

Sorry for the confusion.